# user based settings handling in php

Tags: php, authorization, settings, acl, access-control

I have an application which will do role based and activity based authorization and access control , now have some needs for "user" based settings.

Have any open source third party library in php, which I can use or refer? Or any easy methodology I can adapt?

Comment: If you create a role for every user, you have "user" based settings right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I got your question right but here is my idea:
I assume you are using some form of database.

**Idea 1:**
Safe a set of rights with every user (e.g. boolean values "edit", "create" or something like that)
*Pro:*
High flexebility in which user is allowed to do what.
*Cons:*
Every user has his own set of rights, thus you have quite a lot of data floating around your database.

**Idea 2:**
Safe a set of groups or roles wich get different rights and you assign a group or a role to a user.
*Pros:*
Rather low amount of data.
*Cons:*
Lower flexebility if you don't want to make a group for every user wich would lead to Idea 1.


I hope that helped and I hope I din't get your question wrong!